# I am unable to get the date box to display - multiDatesPicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I have spent a week trying to get a multiselect date picker to work. Of all the components I have tried  multiDatesPicker fits the bill but I cannot get it to work. I even downloaded the same versions of the two included jquery .js files they use in the example. Please can someone help me I have to have this finished by the end of the month.

below is the downloaded example code

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- includes jquery, jquery ui and multidatespicker scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    // initiate the multiDatesPicker.
    // Note that you can still use jQuery UI datepicker options (and events and methods too :)
    $('#calendar').multiDatesPicker({
      minDate: +1, // jQuery UI datepicker option
      addDates: ['26/09/2010', '01/12/2010'] // multidatepicker option
    });

    // shows selected dates in an alert message
    $('#show_dates').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var dates = $('#calendar').multiDatesPicker('getDates');
      var dates_in_string = '';
      for(d in dates) dates_in_string+= dates[d]+' ';
      alert(dates_in_string);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
  <button id="show_dates">Show selected dates!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked all three .js files load OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing is because the [`addDates`](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#option-addDates) option is localization dependent:

> Adds an array of dates specified in a string, milliseconds or
>   javascript date object format.
>   NOTE: the string format you should
>   pass to multiDatePicker depends on the localization of datepicker, see
>   this page for more infos on how to configure it.

If you check the console there is the error raised from jQuery-UI script:

> Uncaught Invalid date

If you not locate the datepicker it use US/ENG notation; so your date must be set as:

```
$('#calendar').multiDatesPicker({
    minDate: +1, // jQuery UI datepicker option
    addDates: ['09/26/2010', '12/01/2010'] // multidatepicker option
});
```

Working demo: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

If you want to set a different date format use the [`dateFormat`](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#custom-date-format-demo) option:

```
$('#calendar').multiDatesPicker({
    minDate: +1, // jQuery UI datepicker option
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",   
    addDates: ['26/09/2010', '01/12/2010'] // multidatepicker option
});
```

Working demo: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

PS: if you can, please, update your jQuery version

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the time you have spent in answering my question. I do have the latest version of jquery but downloaded the older version in case the problem was caused by an incompatibility problem.

Comment: You need not to download that. Simple add `<script src="http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>` this in the scripts.

Comment: @Irvin Dominin sorry stupid comment in here, please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/dauruk0512/dnqowp3o/1/ i just make in external resources but it doesn't working ? but after i make in html with it working fine
`<script src=""></script>`my question is why ? please don't vote down cause i'm new at this forum, thanks